# Chronicle Queue: Client id file not present

Tags: docker, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I'm experimenting with running chronicle queue inside docker containers. Why do I get the following error only when running in a container, and not when running directly on host?

What is this `.chronicle.analytics.client.id` file used for?

```
Client id file not present: /root/.chronicle.analytics.client.id java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /root/.chronicle.analytics.client.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `~/.chronicle.analytics.client.id` is created unless it already exists and will contain a random UUID number used by Google Analytics as per https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/blob/ea/DISCLAIMER.adoc

The message is not an error but an information message.

Using the link above, you can get information on how to turn off this.